# Unix sockets .sock file

Tags: sockets, unix, operating-system

I am new to socket programming. I have built a basic client-server architecture where the client connects to a particular IP address and port. This works perfectly for windows. But, the same does not work for Mac. On googling out, I found that I need to create a .sock file instead of the ip address and port. The client can communicate with server using this .sock file. But, I was wondering why do we have this difference with Windows here. Also, does unix sockets internally resolve to some ip address and port from the .sock file ? Please help me in understanding this better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If on Linux, read [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) first

Comment: Windows likes splitting from the group of OSes and showing it's different. It's a matter of fact.

Comment: Meh - sounds more like the Mac is non-standard:(

Comment: Creating a `.sock` file? OSX is a Unix variant, its network API works mainly as all Unix boxes, no need for such a weird `.sock`file... Something else goes wrong in your code. `.sock` files are used for Unix domain sockets and it is only a naming convention.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch is that not `man 4 unix`?

Comment: Not on Linux, where `unix`  sockets are in section 7 of man pages