# .sock file "Conection refused" when NGINX on docker container, uWSGI on macOS

Tags: django, macos, docker, nginx, uwsgi

I installed Django, uWSGI and Docker on my Mac, then i run a NGINX docker image for serving web with sharing my project directory.

```
docker run -v ~/Projects:/Projects -v /Projects/My-Project/My-Project_nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/My-Project_nginx.conf:ro -p 80:80 -d nginx
```

After i start uWSGI and test, NGINX got error `"111: Connection refused"`:

```
2017/08/09 05:38:00 [error] 18#18: *11 connect() to unix:///Projects/My-Project/My-Project.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: 172.16.10.30, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///Projects/My-Project/My-Project.sock:", host: "172.16.10.30", referrer: "http://172.16.10.30/"
172.17.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2017:05:38:00 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "http://172.16.10.30/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

The problem seems on my Mac, Because i tested them worked on Ubuntu. Sharing .sock file is fine.

Someone said "[Socket sharing is possible, but not supported on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576942/unix-sockets-sock-file)", is that true? Why? Can i fix it some way?

Or, some better way for my case? I know `docker-compose` is born for this, but i want more flexible way for assembling by my own and less rely on internet.

---

#### NGINX_conf

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name 172.16.10.30;
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /media  {
        alias /Projects/My-Project/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /Projects/My-Project/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  unix:///Projects/My-Project/My-Project.sock;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

#### uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
project = My-Project

chdir = /Projects/%(project)

master = true
processes = 2

socket = %(project).sock
wsgi-file = %(project)/wsgi.py

chmod-socket = 666

vacuum = true

py-autoreload = 1
```

Comment: Get inside your container using `docker exec -it nginxcontainerid bash`. In that bash check if you are able to see the socket files or not

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes! Of cource, i had tested on Ubuntu, it works. Can .sock file shared on macOS?